# Google Analytics list of page views with timestamps?

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to export a list of all page views, with timestamps, out of google analytics?

Currently I can see page views per day, but not specific times for each view. I do see real-time data as it comes in, so I assume the time for each view is being stored.

If not, how might I go about sending that data when I report the page view in a way that will make it accessible in the dashboard?

Comment: Not related to coding so off-topic, but you could try a custom report with dimensions of Page, Hour, and Minute. There is no "seconds" dimension, unless you create it yourself. Also note that you can't get a real-time report in this way.

Answer (score 3):

[[UPDATE]] The Google Analytics v4 API now includes a "dateHourMinute" dimension.

Inside Google Analytics, I think the problem you will run into is that a "timestamp" includes Date, Hour, Minute, Second (and maybe millisec) and you can only drill into one secondary dimension at a time (ie: just date). An alternative method is to use the query explorer or just use the Google Analytics API.

**Ad Hoc Report with query explorer**

You can use the Google Analytics API Explorer: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

It will allow you to select:

- A date range
- Metrics: (like Users, pageviews, etc)
- Dimensions: pagePath, Date, Hour, Minute (can't go to second or further, as in a timestamp, though)
- Use filters to get rid of some data.

If your website gets a decent amount of traffic (> 50,000 pageviews per month), you might want to grab it 1 month (or less) at a time to avoid hitting limits/sampling effects.

Answer (score 0):

@doctaj solution works. Please just note that if you are using the query-explorer for example, "dateHourMinute" dimension is considered 3 dimensions and will burn 3 spots from your available 7 or 10 dimensions that you can query. So if you need more dimensions, you need to decide which is more important to you. For example, you may want to query for the date and hour dimensions separately to drop the minutes in favour of something else.